# How can I animate the growth of a hair particle when using an object as a particle?

Tags: animation, particles

How can you do that when using a group configuration? I want to grow leaves and trees. but the END parameter disapears when using group or object.

Comment: you can control size of object/group with Hair Length or Size under the render tab in particle system.